# Faster results from database using php for hotel search based on each date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am developing a hotel search engine. It has tables like `hotel info`, `hotel availability` for each and every date. It works fine but the results are slow compared to other hotel search engines like easytobook or hotel.com. My question is: How can I make it faster? At present its directly fetching results from database using PHP.

This is current query that is being used for fetching results from the database

```
SELECT DISTINCT t_hotel_info.hotelid, 
                t_hotel_info.hotelname, 
                t_hotel_info.description, 
                t_hotel_info.userid, 
                t_hotel_info.starrating, 
                t_hotel_info.currency, 
                t_hotel_info.hotel_url, 
                t_hotel_info.address1, 
                t_hotel_info.state, 
                t_hotel_info.country, 
                t_hotel_images1.imagepath1 
FROM   t_hotel_info 
       INNER JOIN t_hotel_images1 
               ON t_hotel_info.userid = t_hotel_images1.userid 
       INNER JOIN t_hotel_availability 
               ON t_hotel_info.userid = t_hotel_availability.userid 
       INNER JOIN t_hotel_account_info 
               ON t_hotel_info.userid = t_hotel_account_info.userid 
       INNER JOIN t_hotel_facilities 
               ON t_hotel_info.userid = t_hotel_facilities.userid 
WHERE  city = '$_GET[city]' 
       AND t_hotel_availability.sdate >= '$_GET[checkin]' 
       AND t_hotel_availability.sdate < '$_GET[checkout]' 
       AND t_hotel_availability.roomrate <> 0
```

here is my explain statement of the tables

```
id  select_type  table                 type  possible_keys  key      key_len  ref   rows   Extra
1   SIMPLE       t_hotel_facilities    ALL   NULL           NULL     NULL     NULL  627    Using temporary
1   SIMPLE       t_hotel_info          ref   PRIMARY        PRIMARY  4         ezee2book.t_hotel_facilities.UserID   8  Using where
1   SIMPLE       t_hotel_account_info  ALL   NULL           NULL     NULL     NULL  767    Using where; Using join buffer
1   SIMPLE       t_hotel_images1       ALL   NULL           NULL     NULL     NULL  732    Using where; Using join buffer
1   SIMPLE       t_hotel_availability  ALL   NULL           NULL     NULL     NULL  51806  Using where; Distinct; Using join buffer
```

Comment: Without knowing the structure of your database, tables and their indexing, and the queries you're using (with an EXPLAIN) there's little we can do to help: we need the details

Comment: At least paste something you have tried.

Comment: SO you've added the query: What about the table structure for the tables you're using in your query, together with their indexes, and an EXPLAIN?

Comment: Please post the output of `explain select distinct t_hotel_info.hotelid, ...`. Please have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain-output.html#explain-output-interpretation for an interpretation of its output. This is under the assumption that you are using MySQL.

Comment: For starters you could try removing `JOINS` when you don't use them. Such as (in this case) `t_hotel_account_info` and `t_hotel_facilities`. And by the JOIN with the `t_hotel_facilities` I can tell your DB is set up pretty bad. Are facilities really bound to the user of the hotel?

Comment: Stop immediatly using this query, it is vurnable to SQL injections, please have a look at http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-Injection

Comment: From the EXPLAIN, looks like you don't have many indexes on your tables: at least set an index on t_hotel_availability.sdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm pretty sure you can prune it a bit:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t_hotel_info.hotelid, 
                t_hotel_info.hotelname, 
                t_hotel_info.description, 
                t_hotel_info.userid, 
                t_hotel_info.starrating, 
                t_hotel_info.currency, 
                t_hotel_info.hotel_url, 
                t_hotel_info.address1, 
                t_hotel_info.state, 
                t_hotel_info.country, 
                t_hotel_images1.imagepath1 
FROM   t_hotel_info 
       INNER JOIN t_hotel_images1 
               ON t_hotel_info.userid = t_hotel_images1.userid 
       INNER JOIN t_hotel_availability 
               ON t_hotel_info.userid = t_hotel_availability.userid 
WHERE  city = '$_GET[city]' 
       AND t_hotel_availability.sdate >= '$_GET[checkin]' 
       AND t_hotel_availability.sdate  0 
       AND t_hotel_availability.roomrate <> 0
```

Those additional `JOIN` statements are killing you.

Further, when it comes to performance, I have a look at two things first:

1. Query Plan Cache
2. Indexing

### Query Plan Cache

Many people will argue over this, but I've seen it personally. It's often better to take a query, one of this size especially, and turn it into a stored procedure. Why? Because the query plan is cached. Remember that a significant amount of effort is spent by the server just determining **how** to run the query.

Database engines, as of late, have gotten a little smarter about caching plans. For example, if you were to parameterize your query, instead of sending raw values in the `WHERE` clause (oh, and I'm not going to mention SQL Injection), it could cache that query plan after the first run.

### Indexing

Indexing is going to be the key, most likely. Most importantly, though I love me a covered index, you want to make sure it's not **scanning** the table. So, for example, you would want to make sure that there is an index on `city` as well as one on `sdate`. This will allow the engine to leverage an ordered index to filter the query at least.

A covered index, which is where you really start seeing performance increases, isn't realistic here because you're pulling back so many fields. If by chance you don't need all these fields, then trim them down, and you may be able to leverage a covered index as well.

Comment: thanks for your time and replies, but these are required.

Comment: @The Solution: but how come the big hotel search engines get results in seconds

Comment: @user2625307, performance is a massive mix of technologies. They may have significant hardware over what you have. They have probably spent weeks, if not months, doing some of things I just mentioned surrounding indexing and query optimization. Just because you may need all this data, doesn't mean you need it in one pass. Maybe you build a more optimal query to get the results for the users and then grab the rest of the data when they click on the tile for more information. See, it seems to me you **don't** need all this data just to display the search results. But again, it takes some work.

Comment: any question please? is it better to convert the given query to xml/json for faster results and again pulling from xml/json

Comment: @user2625307, the issue may be the amount of data (i.e. you're not paging the data at all), but it's not going to be the form in which it's transferred. If you're giving users results, and it's returning thousands of results, then one issue is that you're not paging. Again, you're going to have to look at a **lot of things** to get the performance they have friend.

Comment: @the solution i am using jquery pagination. dhitrax.com is the site

Comment: @user2625307, jQuery pagination doesn't do anything for the query. That's all user interface stuff. You're fighting a much more complex problem than I think you realize. The query needs to load one page at a time, the interface needs to visualize that, the tables need indexed, and the query needs pruned. Only pull back what you need when you need it, and make a round-trip to show users the details of a possible reservation. Further, load your panes in stages if necessary to give the users a seamless experience. My friend, it's complex, and you probably need to do some studying on the subject.